# How can I programatically forward TCP connections in Python?

Tags: python, iptables, portforwarding

I would like to programmatically redirect incoming TCP connections on the local machine to other machines and conditionally change them to other machines

For example I'd like to forward incoming connections on port `9001` to `www.google.com:80` then after sometime I would like to close 9001 on the local machine and instead start forwarding incoming connections on `9400` to `www.yahoo.com:80` or potentially have both forwarding rules in operation at the same time.

I initially thought I could do this with iptables but I'm not sure. I've also looked at TCP socket proxies, but I'm not interested in the content of the connections just being able to redirect and close them programatically.

Comment: You can accomplish this using a cronjob and iptables if you are on a linux machine.

Comment: I meant conditionally instead of periodically. How can I do this with iptables as they don't allow hostnames only IPs?

Comment: If you want conditionally instead of periodically, make a daemon which listens for condition changes and updates iptables. IP addresses are resolved from hostnames before updating iptables upon condition changes.

Comment: Check out the [firewalld](https://fedorahosted.org/firewalld/) project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) library to create a connection to the TCP port that you want to communicate with, and continuously read from the socket until you have as much data / have read for as long as you want to, similar to

```
conn_in  = socket.create_connection((from_host, from_port))
conn_out = socket.create_connection((to_host, to_port)) 
...
while time() - start_time < desired_time:
    buffer = conn_in.recv(4096)
    conn_out.send(buffer)
```

And you can put conditionals around that as you see fit. Does this seem to help?

Comment: What happens if the communication needs to be bidirectional (and full-duplex)?

Comment: So the connection created by the create_connection initializer allows for both sockets to both `send` and `recv`. So you could simply read from both into their own buffer, process, and send back to either/both if you so choose. I'm having difficulty understanding why bidirectionality is problematic for this approach.

Comment: I was only stating that your code covers only one direction.